# How can I observe the event that UITabBar is hidden or not?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I use the method `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` when push, and at many places, the UITabBar needs hidden when push and not hidden when pop back, so How can I observe the event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delegate or notification for you to know if tabBar is visible. You can check the window property of tabBar

```
if tabBarController!.tabBar.window == nil {

}
```

or hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

```
if hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {

}
```

to work around.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.As your 2nd method,  I can get the hidden status  when vc pushes, but how to get the visible status when pop back ?

Answer (score 9):

There is actually another way to observer if when a UITabBar is hidden or not, it's by using Key-Value Observing (KVO). I had a similar problem and used it to find when the `tabBar` got displayed or hidden.

It can look like something like this.

```swift
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
  // custom code

  var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

  convenience init() {
      self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
      
      observation = observe(
          \.tabBar.isHidden,
          options: [.old, .new]
      ) { object, change in
          print("TabBar isHidden changed from : \(change.oldValue), updated to: \(change.newValue)")
      }
  }

  deinit { 
      observation = nil
  }
}
```

If use this in production, make sure you remove the observer and follow best practice for KVO. Hope it helps.

Comment: this is the best way to watch tabbar visibility changes